# Change Value on SQL View

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following table:

```
ID     myDate       myTime     Value
1      2014-06-01   00:00:00   100
2      2014-06-01   01:00:00   125
3      2014-06-01   02:00:00   132
4      2014-06-01   03:00:00   139
5      2014-06-01   04:00:00   145
6      2014-06-01   05:00:00   148
FF.
24     2014-06-01   23:00:00   205
25     2014-06-02   00:00:00   209
26     2014-06-02   01:00:00   215
27     2014-06-02   02:00:00   223
```

Then I have the following SQL Statement:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE myDate = '2014-06-01'
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE myDate = DATEADD(dd, 1, '2014-06-01') AND myTime = '00:00:00'
```

So the result should be from record number 1 to record number 25.
What I am trying to do is `myTime` value with `00:00:00` on the last record, need to change to `24:00:00`.

Does anyone know how to do this? Or is not possible?

Thank you.

Comment: When you say "change", do you mean you want to change what appears in the output without updating the database, or do you want to change the actual original value stored in the database?

Comment: @LarryLustig, Yes.. Without updatating the database. Just viewing on the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use simple IIF function of SQL Server: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/hh213574.aspx

So the query will be like the below

```
SELECT 
ID, 
myDate, 
IIF(myTime='00:00:00', '24:00:00', myTime) as myTime 
FROM MyTable WHERE myDate = '2014-06-01'
```

*Please mark as answer if it answers your question*

Update: 
If it is sql server 2008 or earlier you can use case.. when

```
    SELECT ID,
            myDate,
            case when CAST(myTime AS VARCHAR(8))='00:00:00' then '24:00:00'
            else CAST(myTime AS VARCHAR(8))
            end as myTimeTemp 
            FROM MyTable WHERE myDate = '2014-06-01'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ID,
            myDate,
            case when CAST(myTime AS VARCHAR(8))='00:00:00' then '24:00:00'
            else CAST(myTime AS VARCHAR(8))
            end as myTimeTemp  
    FROM MyTable WHERE myDate = DATEADD(dd, 1, '2014-06-01') AND myTime = '00:00:00'
```

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2008. Check my question tag.

Comment: The error said, incorrect syntax near '='. IIF Applies to: SQL Server (SQL Server 2012 through current version), Azure SQL Database.. Check this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/hh213574.aspx

Comment: Ok, in 2008, it seems IIF is not enabled. you can use case..when.. 
check the update of the answer above

Comment: Incorrect syntax near ')' ... Fyi, the datatype for myTime is Time(7)

Comment: Can you try with this one:

   SELECT 
    ID, 
    myDate, 
    case when myTime='00:00:00' then '24:00:00'
        else myTime
        end as myTime 
    FROM MyTable WHERE myDate = '2014-06-01'

Comment: Error said, converting failed from time to string

Comment: Okay, use cast to varchar then

  SELECT 
    ID, 
    myDate, 
    case when CAST(myTime AS VARCHAR(8))='00:00:00' then '24:00:00'
        else CAST(myTime AS VARCHAR(8))
        end as myTimeTemp

Comment: As a note, `case` is preferable the `iif()`.  `case` is standard SQL.  `iif()` is something that MS Access uses.

Comment: Use the latest one:

 SELECT 
    ID, 
    myDate, 
    case when CAST(myTime AS VARCHAR(8))='00:00:00' then '24:00:00'
        else CAST(myTime AS VARCHAR(8))
        end as myTimeTemp

Comment: Thanks Gordon, for this info!

Comment: @masum7, still the same mate, error converting time to string

Comment: Haminteu, you tried with the latest one right? Is there any null value in the time field?

 SELECT 
    ID, 
    myDate, 
    case when CAST(myTime AS VARCHAR(8))='00:00:00' then '24:00:00'
        else CAST(myTime AS VARCHAR(8))
        end as myTimeTemp 
    FROM MyTable

Comment: @masum7, Yes, the last one. Error Message: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Comment: @masum7, The error coming from the first select statement. The first select statement also need to convert to string. Now is OK. Cheers mate,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60768/discussion-between-haminteu-and-masum7).

Comment: @masum7, The first select statement, don't need to change from '00:00:00' to '24:00:00'

Answer (score 0):

A couple comments.  First, any reason you're storing the date and time in different columns?  Seems like that could be simplified to store in a single column.

Regardless, no need for `UNION ALL` in this case, a simple `OR` statement would return the results you're looking for.

To answer you're question, if you want to update the last results from 00:00 to 24:00, something like this should do the trick without the need for `OR` or `UNION`:

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET mytime = '24:00:00'
WHERE myDate = DATEADD(dd, 1, '2014-06-01') AND myTime = '00:00:00'
```

No need for `DATEADD` if you're hard coding the date (just use '2014-06-02'), but I assume it's a passed in variable.

---

Edit, given your comments, this should work using a `CASE` statement:

```
SELECT ID, 
       myDate, 
       CASE WHEN myDate = DATEADD(day, 1, '2014-06-01') 
            THEN DATEADD(hour, 24, myTime)
            ELSE myTime
       End newMyTime,
       Value
FROM MyTable
WHERE mydate = '2014-06-01' OR 
     (myDate = DATEADD(day, 1, '2014-06-01') AND myTime = '00:00:00')
```

Comment: Yes, you're right. I don't need UNION ALL. Thanks. But What I meant is without updating the value itself. Just viewing the result.

Comment: @Haminteu -- take a look at the edits.  You can achieve this with a `case` statement...

Answer (score 0):

You would do this with an `or`:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE myDate = '2014-06-01' OR
      (myDate = DATEADD(dd, 1, '2014-06-01') AND myTime = '00:00:00');
```

EDIT:

```
SELECT date('2014-06-01') as mydate,
       (case when mydate <> date('2014-06-01') then '24:00:00' else mytime end) as mytime,
       REST OF COLUMNS HERE
FROM MyTable
WHERE myDate = '2014-06-01' OR
      (myDate = DATEADD(dd, 1, '2014-06-01') AND myTime = '00:00:00');
```

Comment: Thank you.. But how can I change the value 00:00:00 to 24:00:00 on the select statement after UNION ALL? Cheers

Comment: @Haminteu . . . There is no `union all` in my query, but I think the edit might do what you want.